# Android how to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() corretly

Tags: java, android

Android how to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

How can i use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to read/write a image from the SD card ? or is there a better way to do it?

I did use the source to download e save the image:

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlBaseImagem + icone);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        //
        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream                
        //File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/cardapioweb/rest/");

        if(directory.exists() == false){
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        File outputFile = new File(directory, icone);

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            //publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

        Log.w("CardapioWeb:" , "Imagem " + outputFile.toString() + " salva no sdcard");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
```

I did use the source to load e show the image:

```
File arq = new File(this.sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/cardapioweb/rest/" + filialDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICONE));

//verifica se a imagem foi baixada com sucesso
if(arq.exists() == true){
        //deve exibir a imagem do sdcard
        File outputFile1 = new File(this.sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/cardapioweb/rest/", filialDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICONE));
        Drawable imagem = Drawable.createFromPath(outputFile1.toString());
        holder.tvWeatherImage.setImageDrawable(imagem);
 }
```

The above codes works perfectly fine on the emulator (Android Virtual Device) with Eclipse !!!!
But when I generate the apk and install on my Galaxy S4, the app can not read images (no error is generated). Just does not display the images. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put a log in your code to see what

```
outputFile1.toString();
```

actually points to, is it what you expect?

Personally, I would have used outputFile1.getAbsolutePath(); NOT the line below:

```
Drawable imagem = Drawable.createFromPath(outputFile1.toString());
```